# Is shelve in Python thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, shelve

Is shelve in Python used for data persistence thread safe? If not, what's a good alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [standard library documentation about the Shelve module, under the heading Restrictions](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#restrictions):

> The **shelve module does not support
>   concurrent read/write access** to
>   shelved objects. (Multiple
>   simultaneous read accesses are safe.)

I would assume that it's probably implementation dependent and in which case, in order to be sure, I would conclude that it certainly is not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the next parts of the documentation, it says: “When a program has a shelf open for writing, no other program should have it open for reading or writing. Unix file locking can be used to solve this, but this differs across Unix versions and requires knowledge about the database implementation used.” - this suggests that the shelve module is not thread safe unless you implement your own locking mechanism. Do you have an example that demonstrates otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatives: ZODB

http://www.zodb.org/

Comment: (from link) (ZODB...) Transactions provide isolation
    Transactions allow multiple logical threads (threads or processes) to access databases and the database prevents the threads from making conflicting changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
Threads = # amount of threads

thread_moment = [False for _ in range(Threads)] 

def job(x):  # x would be the index of the thread  

    lock.aquire()

    # open/edit/update/close your shelve file

    thread_moment[x] = True 

    lock.release()

    while True:
        if all(thread_moment) == True:
            thread_moment = [False for _ in range(threads)]
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

    # carry on with your script
```

Comment: the question is about whether it's safe.. how does your code answer the question?